# MySQL Sum values in column based on type column

Tags: mysql

I have two columns called `value` and `type`.  I want to sum all the values in my table together, but when the type is `'alpha'` I want to add them and when the type is `'beta'` I want to subtract them.  Assuming that type is a varchar and value is a numeric type, how do I do this?  Is there a built in function for this or do I need to define my own?

Comment: post tables and desired results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work. Note that I used column names `theValue` and `theType` instead of `value` and `type`.

```
SELECT SUM(IF(theType = 'alpha', theValue, 0)) - SUM(IF(theType = 'beta', theValue, 0)) AS theNetResult
FROM mytable;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02016/2)

Comment: Clever use of sum.  Thanks!

Comment: How can I express this as a function so I only have to say something like `getTotal()` whenever I want the total rather than typing that out each time? (Sorry I don't have much experience in SQL)

Comment: @Kvass You can either create an in-code function that calls this SQL statement and returns the result, or you can look into [stored procedures and functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html). Exactly how to do either of those is outside the scope of this question though.

Answer (score 1):

This is another way to do the same

```
 SELECT SUM(IF(theType = 'alpha', theValue,(theValue*-1))) AS NetResult
FROM mytable;
```